# Bitcoind under Windows 7; RPC port 8882 not opening

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, windows

Using Win7 64 bit I'm trying to get bitcoind (v0.8.5) to work.

Bitcoin.conf has the following content (in the %appdata%\bitcoin dir):
rpcuser=12345
rpcpassword=12345

I run using command line: bitcoind -rpcpassword=12345

I then use the NIRSOFT app cports-x64 which shows list of open TCP/IP and UDP ports on computer. Bitcoind is in the list but only with port 8883.

Why is the RPC connection not working such that port 8882 (default RPC port) is open and mapped to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running `bitcoind` with the `-server` option set as well as `-rpcuser` and `-rpcpass`. These can alternatively be set as lines in your `bitcoin.conf`. The RPC port will only be open on 8332 if all three of these options are correctly set.

Comment: bitcoind -server -rpcuser=USER_NAME -rpcpassword=PASSWORD with bitcoin.conf : rpcuser=USER_NAME
rpcpassword=PASSWORD
rpcallowip=*                      still no open port on 8332!

Comment: `-printtoconsole` and check the output.

Answer (score 1):

QT's RPC API is set to listen by default to TCP port 8332.

Since you have specified the **rpcuser** and **rpcpassword** parameters in the bitcoin.conf file you don't need to explicitly specify them upon your call.

In a Command Prompt, run: **bitcoind.exe -daemon -debugnet -printtoconsole** and then open a new Command Prompt and type: **netstat -a**, once the RPC API is listening for connections you should see this: **TCP  127.0.0.1:8332  myHostName:0  LISTENING**